# product of GCD of all the subsets of set having n elements

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, greatest-common-divisor

I want to find the (product of GCD's of all the subsets of the set S )MOD 1000000007.I have a set of numbers n where n can be 10^5. Can i generate any recurrence to find the GCD of all the subsets of set. The problem can be solved by just finding all the subsets and then finding the GCD of each but this is not the right approach to this type of question. How can i proceed?

Comment: @MOehm I am not able to understand the solution. Can u explain ?

Comment: No, but your problem has obviously been discussed two days ago. Asking the question again is not likely to yield a better or easier solution.